# Problem with regular expression!

Tags: javascript, regex

I have used the following pattern for the regular expression for the phone number

```
pattern="[0-9 -+]+$";
```

The phone number may contain numbers, hyphen(-), space and plus(+). It works when i use numbers only. When numbers and alphabets are used it does not work.

What can be the problem, please do let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So `9++23++-13` is a valid phone number?

Answer (score 7):

It is interpreting the - as part of a range. try this:

```
pattern="^[0-9 +-]+$";
```

The - either needs escaping (`\-`) or moving to the end like this (thanks Tim).

Comment: I edited the answer a bit: The + doesn't need to be escaped, and neither does the - if you put it at the beginning or end of the character class.

Comment: @Fabien: `\s` contains tabs, too.

Comment: @Tim: yep, \s should be " ", sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex will fail even after making the correction suggested by David. Because it matches any combination of one or more numbers and +, -. For example, it matches `99++++--12`

Here is a better version that matches numbers in the format 999-999-9999 with an optional leading country code in the format +9999 (two to four digits long)

```
(\+\d{2,4}\s*)?(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})
```

Comment: Well, this won't match UK numbers unless you put hyphens in them in odd places. Correct international form for a London number, for example, would be +44 20 xxxx xxxx.

Comment: Matching all locales is a difficult task (in India it is `+91 \d{10}`) - that's why I specifically said it matches 3+3+4 numbers. I was just pointing out the faults of `[0-9+-]` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to start with a ^ and the - needs to be escaped with a \

```
pattern=/^[0-9 \-+]+$/;
```

It needs to start with a ^ as that is an anchor for the start of the string, if you didn't it would validate strings that started with anything, as long as they ended with a number, space, - or +

`-` needs to be escaped as it is a special character and has a meaning other than `-`. While `+` is a special character, and if you want to treat it as a `+` outside a class it needs to be escaped, when inside a class only `]^-\` need to be escaped.

So outside of a class escape

```
.^$|*+?()[{\
```

And inside escape:

```
]^-\
```

However, most implementations allow you to escape all 12 special characters inside classes without error, and they will only give an error if you escape a non special character, which means that this (Note the extra `\` before the plus) will also work fine.

```
pattern="^[0-9 \-\+]+$"
```

I always find that using [a regex tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) makes things easier as it allows me to see mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Since **-** (dash) is used as the range symbol inside brackets in regexp you need to either escape it, or place it last:

```
pattern="[0-9 \-+]+$";
// or
pattern="[0-9 +-]+$";
```

You might also want to begin the regexp with **^** to make sure the whole string matches it, not just the end:

```
pattern="^[0-9 +-]+$";
```